# Remove :focus and its style after mousewheel click

Tags: javascript, css, focus

Got an issue and no ideas for solving this.

I have some link  in my HTML, to which I apply :hover and :focus+:active CSS styles (here's example):
https://codepen.io/Auditive/pen/WVrRKJ

When I'm clicking such link by mousewheel (for opening in other tab) - the :focus & :active CSS styles remain.

I'm looking for ways to remove :focus & :active styles from clicked link.
For example, maybe smth like:

```
function RemoveFocus() {
  var link = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  link.addEventListener("click", function() { 
      link.blur();
      });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57160468/10761855

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `getElementsByTagName` returns an HTML Collection which doesn't have an `addEventListener` property. You need to use a specific HTML node like `link[0]` (you could use a more specific query like giving the link an id and use `getElementById`).

Most importantly, the middle click doesn't fire a click event, but it does fire a `mouseup` event so you can use the `which` property of the event to find out if the mouseup comes from the middle click button.

**Note**: In order to make a snippet in this answer I used a self executing function to call the RemoveFocus function.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400&display=swap');

body {
  background: #282828;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #8f8;
}

.block {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #787878;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1%;
  margin-top: 2.5%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #fff8;
}

a, a:link, a:visited {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:link:hover, a:visited:hover {
  font-weight: 300;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #fff 42.5%, #4285f4, #ea4336, #fbbc04, #4285f4, #34a853, #ea4336);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff4;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

/*https://loading.io/spinners/comets/lg.comet-spinner.gif*/

a:focus, a:link:focus, a:visited:focus,
a:active, a:link:active, a:visited:active {
  color: transparent;
  background-image: url(https://loading.io/spinners/comets/lg.comet-spinner.gif);
  background-size: 20%;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-clip: border-box;
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p />Click on link with mousewheel
  <div class="block">
    <a href="https://google.com" />Link 2 Google
  </div>
  <script>
      function RemoveFocus() {
      var link = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
      link[0].addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
        if( e.which == 2 ) {
          this.blur();
       }
      });
    }

    (function() {
        RemoveFocus();
    })();
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand a mistake made by myself. Your code works as needed. I just added setTimeout for 1 sec.

Comment: After I add this example to my webpage - i catch:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined.

On that row:
  link[0].addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {

Comment: That is probably because the query `getElementsByTagName` returns an empty array and accessing `link[0]` gives you undefined. Where are you calling RemoveFocus?

Comment: It's self-calling from mypage.js, where I add it as you show on snippet. .js loads in HTML page by <script src=mypage.js>.

Comment: Maybe the DOM is not loaded yet, is the script at the end of the body?

Comment: I'll try to insert it direct into HTML page.
And also would try to add 'document.ready' at beginning.

Answer (score 1):

First you need get first element of array

`var link = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];`

and then handle two events:

`link.addEventListener("click", clickHandle);`

`link.addEventListener("auxclick", clickHandle);`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p />Click on link with mousewheel
    <div class="block">
        <a href="https://www.google.ru/" />Link 2 Google
    </div>
    <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400&display=swap');

    body {
        background: #282828;
    }

    p {
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: 300;
        color: #8f8;
    }

    .block {
        width: 400px;
        height: 50px;
        border: 1px solid #787878;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 1%;
        margin-top: 2.5%;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #fff8;
    }

    a,
    a:link,
    a:visited {
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        font-size: 28px;
        font-weight: 300;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    a:hover,
    a:link:hover,
    a:visited:hover {
        font-weight: 300;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #fff 42.5%, #4285f4, #ea4336, #fbbc04, #4285f4, #34a853, #ea4336);
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff4;
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    }

    /*https://loading.io/spinners/comets/lg.comet-spinner.gif*/

    a:focus,
    a:link:focus,
    a:visited:focus,
    a:active,
    a:link:active,
    a:visited:active {
        color: transparent;
        background-image: url(https://loading.io/spinners/comets/lg.comet-spinner.gif);
        background-size: 20%;
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        -webkit-background-clip: border-box;
        text-shadow: none;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
    var link = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

    function clickHandle(event) {
        //event.preventDefault();
        link.blur();

        return;
    }

    link.addEventListener("click", clickHandle);
    link.addEventListener("auxclick", clickHandle);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hmm, it works on snippet, but after I add this JS to webpage - console shows to me:
Uncaught TypeError: link.addEventListener is not a function.

Comment: @Auditive it's can be problem with `document.getElementsByTagName` in my file i didn't have any another `a` tag

Answer (score 0):

didn't tested the code, but i think this will work:

```
    function RemoveFocus() {
       var link = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
       link.addEventListener("click", function(e) { 
          if( e.which == 2 ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            link.blur();
          }
       });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

add addEventListener "wheel" or "mousewheel" and do what you do for example for your question the use

```js
 function RemoveFocus() {
  var link = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  link.addEventListener("wheel", function() { 
      link.blur();
      });
}
```

then put code what you want